# Rails and assets: how can I add a library with css/js/swf/fonts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I have a new rails application.

I want to add a **javascript** library and it contains a lot of resources.

When I put these files in `app/assets/`, I can't get them from my browser.

Example:
I have `app/assets/img/bg.png`, but when I use the URL `http://localhost:3001/img/bg.png`, I receive only `No route matches [GET] "/img/bg.png"`

Example 2:
I have `app/assets/swf/ZeroClipboard.swf`, but when I use the URL `http://localhost:3001/swf/ZeroClipboard.swf`, I receive only `No route matches [GET] "/swf/ZeroClipboard.swf"`

Example 3 (vendor assets):
I have `app/vendor/swf/ZeroClipboard.swf`, but when I use the URL `http://localhost:3001/swf/ZeroClipboard.swf`, I receive only `No route matches [GET] "/swf/ZeroClipboard.swf"`

Where should I put the library files to have the ability to access them directly?

Rails **4.2**

Comment: They should be accessible through `/assets/*` use the `asset_path` rails helper.

Comment: Ok, but how can I add a library to have the ability to access its files directly?

Comment: I want to put 'http://localhost:3001/swf/ZeroClipboard.swf' in my browser and get ZeroClipboard.swf file. Where should I place it?

Comment: Thats not how the asset pipeline works. I suggest [reading](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html), Alternativly, `public/swf/` should work.

Answer (score 0):

Image assets go in `app/assets/images`.

If you want to serve some assets from `app/assets/img`, you need to add that directory to `config.assets.paths` and then restart your server.

Comment: I've already restarted it, but new directories don't work. I have to add `img`, `swf` and `fonts` directories.

Comment: FYI assets that come from outside sources should ideally be placed in `/vendor/assets`

Comment: Why did you marked it as a duplicate? AFAIK Rails 3 framework has different asset system.

Comment: @MildMildMint http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#upgrading-from-old-versions-of-rails Doesn't seem to be much difference.

Comment: @MildMildMint process for adding paths to `config.assets.paths` is identical